# set default collapsed, in $.ig.GridExcelExporter.exportGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am using `igTreeGrid` to show data in table and export that data into excel file

[Click here For Example](http://www.igniteui.com/tree-grid/export-to-excel)

its working perfect for me but i am facing problem to set exported grid columns width and set excel sheet collapsed by default.

I have searched `$.ig.GridExcelExporter.exportGrid` Documentation but found nothing

is there any way to do this task in `$.ig.GridExcelExporter` or anything else.... ??

I also find some helpful material in this [Link (Click here)](http://blogs.jp.infragistics.com/blogs/mikam/archive/2016/07/28/26764.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Infragistics excel client library currently does not support collapsing or expanding the Outline(group) data.

The columns widths can be configured by using the [exportEnding callback](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ig.gridexcelexporter_tg#options:callbacks.exportEnding).

```js
exportEnding: function(sender, args) {
    var worksheet = args.worksheet;
    var columns = worksheet.columns();

    for (var i = 0; i < columns.count(); i++) {
        var column = columns.item(i);

        // This will set all columns to be 44 pixels
        column.setWidth(44, $.ig.excel.WorksheetColumnWidthUnit.pixel);
    }
}
```